# How to Authenticate WPF Application with AAD B2C to gain access to Azure App Service

Tags: wpf, azure, authentication, azure-ad-b2c, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I'm quite stuck at the moment trying to implement authentication into a project I'm working on.  The end goal of this project is to have two WPF apps and on web based app hosted on Azure.  One WPF app is for an administrator, the other for staff, and lastly the web app for customers.  Each application will be connected to one Azure App Service for a shared database and needs to have authentication so separate all the users.  For authentication I am planning on using Azure Active Directory B2C.

I've been researching and trying to implement this for several days now on one of the WPF apps but as I stated before I'm quite stuck.  From what I understand, the only way to do B2C authentication for WPF is through client managed authentication.  Following the code shown on the Azure tutorial sites, other SO posts, and the Azure Git Repos, I have come up with the following code:

```
   System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
   authResult = await App.PublicClientApp.AcquireTokenAsync(App.ApiScopes,
       GetUserByPolicy(accounts, App.PolicySignUpSignIn), UIBehavior.SelectAccount, 
       string.Empty, null, App.Authority);
   Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject payload = new Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject();
   payload["access_token"] = authResult.AccessToken;
   MobileServiceClient msclient = new MobileServiceClient(App.AzureAppService);
   MobileServiceUser user = await msclient.LoginAsync(
        MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.WindowsAzureActiveDirectory, payload);
```

Everything starts off great and I'm able to get my Sign-In policy to display.  After logging in, I am given an IdToken and an AccessToken.  After creating a JObject and adding the access token to it, I attempt to use it to login with my MobileServiceClient.  But that's where I am having issues.  No matter what I do, no matter what I try, I only get an exception with a 401 Error telling me I'm unauthorized.  And this is the point I've been stuck at for the past few days.

Obviously I'm not doing anything special here and I imagine many people have done this before me but I just can't seem to get past this point and was hoping someone may be able to offer me some guidance.  Am I way off track?  Is there a better way that I could be doing this?  Any suggestions or advice would be greatly appreciated as I am very new to Azure.

Thanks all!

**Update:**

Here's how I have my Azure Settings:

On the app service side

```
Client Id: "{Client Id of the AAD B2C App}"
Issuer URL: "login.microsoft.com{TennatName}.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration"
Allowed Token Audiences: "https://{App Service Name}.azurewebsites.net" (App Service URL)
```

On B2C side:

```
Web and native client enabled
Web Reply URL: "https://{AppServiceName}.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/add/callback"
Native App: I did not know what custom redirect URL to have so I have both
"{TennatName}.onmicrosoft.com://auth/" and 
"{AppServiceName}.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/add/callback"
```

**Update 2:**

```
My authority is login.microsoftonline.com/tfp{tenant}/{policy}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
And my ApiScopes = { "https://{Tenant}/thisisatest/user_impersonation" };
```

Comment: Hi Joshua. How have you configured Azure AD with Azure Mobile Apps? e.g. Client ID, Issuer URL and Allowed Token Audiences?

Comment: Yes I have!  In the app service I have set it up for authentication with AD.  Here's how I have it setup -
App Service:
ClientID: Application Id of the B2C App
Issuer URL: https://login.microsoft.com/{TennatName}.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration

On B2C side:
Web and native client enabled
Web Reply URL: https://{AppServiceName}.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/add/callback
Native App:
I didn't know what custom redirect URL to have so I have both
{TennatName}.onmicrosoft.com://auth/
and
{AppServiceName}.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/add/callback

Comment: Wow that comment did not go nearly as formatted as I put it in.

Comment: Thank you, Joshua, and how do you initialize the `PublicClientApplication` instance (i.e. the constructor arguments)?

Comment: This is how it was initialized in the one of the Azure examples I downloaded from Gihub.
    <pre>
    public static PublicClientApplication PublicClientApp { get; } = new     PublicClientApplication(ClientId, Authority,     TokenCacheHelper.GetUserCache());     <code>

Comment: Cool. What is `Authority` set to? You can obfuscate the tenant name.

Comment: Sorry this is my first post.  I'm still trying to figure out the code formatting on here.
public static string Authority = BaseAuthority.Replace("{tenant}", Tenant).Replace("{policy}", PolicySignUpSignIn);

Comment: <pre>Tenant = "{TenantName}.onmicrosoft.com";
PolicySignUpSignIn = "b2c_1_signin"; <code>

Comment: @ChrisPadgett I updated the original post to add the information and make it a bit more legible.

Comment: So, if I can assume that `Authority` in the client app is set to `https://{your-tenant-name}.b2clogin.com/tfp/{your-tenant-name}.onmicrosoft.com/{your-policy-name}/`, then the issuer URL in the app service must refer to the same metadata i.e. `https://{your-tenant-name}.b2clogin.com/tfp/{your-tenant-name}.onmicrosoft.com/{your-policy-name}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration`.

Comment: Also, the allowed token audiences doesn't look right, what do you set `App.ApiScopes` to?

Comment: @ChrisPadgett I have updated the original post with the authority and `App.ApiScopes`

Comment: @JoshuaStevens You should use https://{your-tenant-name}.b2clogin.com/tfp/{your-tenant-name}.onmicrosoft.com/{your-policy-name} as the authority.

Comment: Thanks you @ChrisPadgett and @Tony Ju.  I set the Authority to `https://{your-tenant-name}.b2clogin.com/tfp/{your-tenant-name}.onmicrosoft.com/{your-policy-name}/` and got an error saying that it could not establish a secure connection.  I then changed the Issuer URL to `https://{your-tenant-name}.b2clogin.com/tfp/{your-tenant-name}.onmicrosoft.com/{your-policy-name}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration` and it appears to be working now.  Thank you guys so so much!  My last question is how do I mark this as answered if there's no listed answer on this post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the authority for the client is set to `https://{your-tenant-name}.b2clogin.com/tfp/{your-tenant-name}.onmicrosoft.com/{your-policy-name}/`, then the issuer URL in the app service must refer to the metadata for this authority; i.e. `https://{your-tenant-name}.b2clogin.com/tfp/{your-tenant-name}.onmicrosoft.com/{your-policy-name}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration`.